# Windows Task Scheduler condition not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have a service i want to start when windows user logs in.
I set a condition to start only if network connection is available, but i'm on AWS EC2 so the connection name keeps changing.

I also tried to use all connection but then my service fails.
Error:
File missing, or condition wasn't met.

did someone encounter such an issue (P.S really hate windows...so much easier on linux)

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your setup? Why not just have start "on login" and not bother checking for a network connection - AWS should always have one I'd have thought.

Comment: you are correct the problem is i need the network cause i want to map a network drive